# look into model object passed into Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I tap into the model object any where in my asp.net mvc application where I issue return Json call? Is there a place in asp.net mvc 4 pipeline where I can tap into my model object after it has been put into "return Json" call? For example, here is my controller action method.. How can I look inside myTestModel in terms of property. I want to be able to do this for all of my return Json calls for any model object.

```
public JsonResult MyTestJsonB()
{
    var myTestModel = new TestModel
        {
            LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow,
            LastModifiedNullable = DateTime.UtcNow,
            TheStrinDateTime = "hello"
        };

    return Json(myTestModel, "text/plain", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: what you mean its not clear to me

Comment: Any where in my asp.net mvc application, in the action method inside my controller, I want to capture what is passed inside my return Json code, the model object, and do some thing with it, so that I have a centralized code. So that my programmers don't have to remember to write a special function every time they need to do return Json at the end of Action method in controller. Makes sense??

Comment: yes makes sense, but according to what I have experience this is not possible

Comment: Sounds like you want an action filter and override OnResultExecuting. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs